# Execution failed for task ':react-native-baidumap-sdk:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, react-native, baidu, baidu-map

I am building a react native application in which I using [react-native-baidumap-sdk](https://github.com/qiuxiang/react-native-baidumap-sdk). When I am trying run the application I am getting below error.

> Execution failed for task
>   ':react-native-baidumap-sdk:compileDebugKotlin'.

Below is my build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.0.0" // or set latest version
         androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
         ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        // classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.41'
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
                // Add jitpack repository (added by react-native-spinkit)
                maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
      //  maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28
                buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: yes, you need to use older version of baidu